# GROUP_CONCAT WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

To show how many users have accepted request for some item ( i.e pending = 0 ) , prefixed with name of user who sends request.

```
items :
item_id  item_name
1         I1
2         I2

profile :
user_id name
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D

user_items :
user_id  shared_by_user_id  pending    item_id
1         2                  1            1
3         2                  0            1
4         2                  0            1
1         2                  1            2
```

### expected Output

```
item_name    users     shared_by_user_id  
I1           B,C,D                 2          
I2           B                     2
```

I have written following query and its output is as below -

```
select item_name, concat(t4.name, ',',group_concat(t3.name)) as users, t1.shared_by_user_id
from user_items t1 
left join item t2 on t2.item_id = t1.item_id
left join profile t3 on t3.user_id = t1.user_id
left join profile t4 on t4.user_id = t1.shared_by_user_id 
where t1.shared_by_user_id = 2 
group by t2.item_id;
```

### Actual Output

```
item_name    users     shared_by_user_id  
I1           B,A,C,D              2          
I2           B,A                  2
```

Clearly, remaining problem is to add a CONDITION for filtering pending = 1 records during GROUP_CONCAT ,but not able to find how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the expression you want for `group_concat()`?

```
concat(t4.name, ',', group_concat(case when pending = 1 then t3.name end)) as users
```

`group_concat()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: I also added IFNULL before group_concat, else concat is setting it NULL